# iAd white banner won't go away

Tags: ios, iad, viewdidload

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 60.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.bannerView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView]; 
}


-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

    [bannerView setDelegate:self];
    [bannerView setAlpha:0];
    bannerView.hidden=YES;
}
```

As soon as viewDidLoad loads and before the iAd loads, there is a white blank fill in banner before iAd banner appears always. I did not set a AdBannerView in storyboard. What can I do to make sure if there is no iAd, for there to also be no white space in its place?

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{  

  admobBannerView=[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

self.admobBannerView.adUnitID = @"UNIT-ID";
self.admobBannerView.rootViewController = self;
self.admobBannerView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.admobBannerView];

GADRequest *request =[GADRequest request];

request.testDevices= @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ]; 

[self.admobBannerView loadRequest:request];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the ad view upon its creation since it takes time for the first ad to load or fail, ex:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 60.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.bannerView setDelegate:self];
    self.bannerView.hidden = YES; <-- Hide it
    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView]; 
}
```

Then make it reappear once the ad loads, ex:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    self.bannerView.hidden = NO;
}
```

And as for the code currently in your `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` method, you don't need to set the alpha to 0 or set the delegate to self again. Also any mention of `bannerView` in `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` should either be `self.bannerView` or `banner`, ex:

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    self.bannerView.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: self.bannerView.hidden=YES; in viewDidLoad makes the banner completely disappear and never appear.  I just need the white space to disappear before the iAd loads.

Comment: @aliya You have to make it reappear in `bannerViewDidLoadAd:`

Comment: That worked for the white space part but now in viewDidLoad iAd and AdMob both show up and no if/else statement with a .hidden=YES/NO is working.

Comment: @aliya I don't know anything else about your code than what you've posted so I don't know anything about the way you're presenting iAd and AdMob at the same time...

Comment: i updated my code on here to show for when iAd fails for AdMob to load.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I got it figured out now how to mediate between iAd/ AdMob.

Comment: @aliya Glad to hear :)